How to use a PCKS12 file with HTTPX?
I have a webservice that requires a client certificate for authentication.
I want to access this webservice using HTTPX (Python), but I don't see how to make this work with my p12 certificate store. It seems that HTTPX needs the certificate file, the privatekey file and the password. Is there no way to directly use the p12 file?
I would like to pass the filepath to the p12 file (or its binary content) plus the password to HTTPX

HTTPX does not directly support loading PKCS12 (.p12) files, but you can use the cryptography library to extract the necessary key and certificate from the PKCS12 file and then pass them to HTTPX


Extract certificate and private keys from pkcs12 store
Install certifi package
Add pem certificates to python's certificates

cat /home/lmc/projects/lmc-local.cert.pem >> /home/lmc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
From the docs

By default, HTTPX uses the CA bundle provided by Certifi.

